# Muscles Won't grow even after following Good diet and Routine

Tags: muscle, muscle-mass, muscle-gain

I have been lifting weights for the past 1 year or so and my muscles barely show, i can see some growth but nothing more then that.

Before starting lifting i was skinny fat(mostly around the waist area),and after following a balanced diet(1:1 ratio) i almost reduced my weight by 18 kg's in 3.5 months and my weight has remained constant throughout the year after that.

So I am really confused that even after following a good diet, sleep pattern and gym routine my muscles won't grow.

Interestingly I have gained a lot of strength over the same period of time.

So can anyone give a tip or point any mistakes that i may be doing that's hampering my growth.

***EDIT***

I am **24** years old **6 ft** and before starting to lift my weight was around **106 kg**  and after 3.5 months my weight dropped to **87 kilos** .

And now i weight around **85 - 86 kilos**

***Nutrition Plan***

I am following the fat loss plan as i have still fat around my waist area
http://www.gurumann.com/Muscular_8_eBook.pdf

Comment: 1:1 ratio of what? How are you objectively **measuring** progress? Generally you need to be eating at a maintenance or surplus to grow muscle.

Comment: So you are lifting, fine. Anyway, we do not know anything about your program. This is a crucial detail to be added.

Comment: If you're not growing, then 99.9% of the time it's going to be a) you're not sleeping enough, b) you're not eating enough, c) you're not progressing your training.

Comment: @JJosaur i am following a 1:1 ratio for carbs and protien and when i look in the mirror i just look the same just with less fat around my waist area.

Comment: @DarkHippo getting arount 5.5 - 6 hrs of quality sleep, and i am increasing the weights thus my strength is increasing

Comment: I'd say you need to sleep 8 - 9 hours a night. Also, how many calories are you consuming and how many grams of protein?

Comment: @Raditz_35 the weight loss I think is mainly due to i stopped eating junk food and preferred home cooked food.but after losing weight i have maintained a good diet so don't you think i should have grown.

Comment: @DarkHippo dont you think the quality matters over quantity, almost 200 gm of protien and 250 - 300 gm carbs

Comment: @Raditz_35 updated the post

Comment: @Raditz_35 I didn't mean to, but most of the fat in body was around the waist area my arms, legs, shoulder were normal.

Comment: That's typical for men. You weren't that heavy, just enough to be called obese.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I have updated the post with my nutrition plan

Comment: Having looked at your re-edited post, if you're following a diet to lose fat (so, eating in a caloric deficit), then there's going to be limited muscle gain. Up the calories for a month and see if you put on some muscle. Also, it would help to include your training plan, as training for fat loss and training for muscle gain have some differences

Comment: Aiming for 0 dietary fat is a really great way to mess up your body. Calorie intake matters most, focus on managing that.

Comment: Between the edited question and answers to comments, there's just this to add: ARE you eating a g protein per pound of bodyweight? What do your total calories look like? What kind of weight training are you doing? Increasing weights is good... but you can get *stronger* (more efficient) without necessarily packing on raw muscle. Which is also good, but not necessarily the goal you're striving for.
So, diet details, and training plan details. And more sleep, if possible... but definitely NOT less!

Comment: With no info on your program, and no specific macro numbers, there's no good answers to this.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by skinny fat you mean that your muscle mass is low. A total mass of 85-86 kg and height of 6 feet (interesting combination of units) would therefore imply that you should lose some 10 more kilograms to reach a bodyfat percentage of about 8-10. It is possible to gain muscle and lose fat simultaneously on a hypocaloric diet but it is usually easier to gain muscle on a hypercaloric diet. In order to maximize muscle gain, you should start the hypercaloric diet in a lean state. Otherwise fat gain will not be as low as it could be. Also you should adjust your training for maximum hypertrophy. Since you have already gained a lot of strength, probably no harm will be done if you focus on hypertrophy. Studies (e.g. *Hubal MJ et al.
Variability in muscle size and strength gain after unilateral resistance training. Med Sci Sports Exerc. 2005 Jun;37(6):964-72*) have shown that people exhibit a wide range of hypertrophic response to resistance training. Some people, around a few percent, gain almost no muscle. You could be among this group but it is not possible to definitely conclude so with the data available. You need to take time to gain knowledge and experience on how you respond to training. My recommendation is to use training programs from reputable authors in order to eliminate rookie mistakes. There is some correlation between strength and hypertrophy gains in individuals but definitely this is not 1:1. Gaining strength but not muscle is not anything out of the ordinary.